# Dual gate fet mixer design problem

Tags: rf, mixer

1-I have designed an LNA amplifier at 5.5 GHz and a Dielectric Resonator at 5GHz.I was hoping to down convert the LNA output using a dual gate mixer (5.5GHz at RF and 5GHz at LO) but none of the dual gate FETs I came across operate at such high frequencies e.g BF998
2-While designing the FET mixer,can I use the S parameters for calculations?Aren't they specified for linear models while mixer is clearly non-linear.

Comment: If you can't find a DG FET at the frequencies you need, consider the similarity between a DG FET and a cascode configuration of 2 normal FETs.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe for such high frequencies you would have better luck using an integrated mixer like the [LTC5510](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/5510fa.pdf) instead of rolling your own.

Excerpt from the datasheet:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

---

**EDIT** (prompted from a comment)

I doubt you can use a BF909 or a 2N25139 up to 5GHz. Look at their datasheets. The BF909 is intended for operation up to 1GHz:

> [image]

While the 2N25139 is specified up to 4GHz (even the non-linear model is valid up to 4GHz):

> [image]

...

> [image]

...

> [image]

---

As an alternative you could use [HEMT devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-electron-mobility_transistor) (JFETs using exotic semiconductor mixes different from plain silicon), but they are darned expensive: see this [search result page on digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40015%2Cfff802eb%2C22c034e&k=hemt&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=0&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=500)!

Here is an excerpt from the datasheet of the first of that list:

> [image]

...

> [image]

Comment: I actually want to design my own circuit.I can use NE25139 or BF998 but have a tough time deciding whether they will operate at such high frequencies or not